# For a linear regression $f$ of $\{(i,y_i)\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$, where $(y_i)$ is non-negative and increasing, is $|y_i - f(i)|$ at most $y_{n-1}$?

Tags: linear-regression

Suppose we have a set of data points $\{(i,y_i)\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$, where $y_i$ are non-negative integers and $(y_i)_{i=0}^{n-1}$ is an increasing sequence.

*Question*: In a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) $f$ for this data set, is it true that the absolute vertical deviation $|y_i - f(i)|$ is at most $y_{n-1}$?

In the following example, $\max_i|y_i - f(i)|$ is quite close to $y_{n-1}$.

[image: extreme example]

This is a follow-up to this question: [For a linear regression of $\{(i,y_i)\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$, where $(y_i)$ is increasing and non-negative, is the $y$-intercept at least $-y_{n-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613207/for-a-linear-regression-of-i-y-i-i-0n-1-where-y-i-is-increasin/1663100)

Comment: In the example above $y_i$ is non-decreasing (as constant) rather than increasing. Also $y_{n-1}=10000$ which is nowhere close to the max absolute difference $|y_i-f(i)|\approx 2000$ as I see it from the image.

Comment: The sequence is {1, 10001, 10002, ..., 10020}, so the max absolute difference is $|y_0 - f(0)| = 8224.3$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed $y_0$ and the fact that $y_i$ slightly increase. You are correct.

Comment: If you replace $y_i$ by $y_i+c$ for some $c$ you change $y_{n+1}$ but not the differences $|y_i-f(i)|$ so the answer is no.

Comment: @Dirk : Yes, you can do the transformation $y_i \mapsto y_i + c$, but $c$ is at least $-y_0$ since $y_i+c$ should be non-negative. The question then asks if $|y_i - f(i)|$ is at most $y_{n-1} - y_0$

Comment: Not sure what you want to say, but large $c$ makes $y_i+c$ large while $|y_i-f(i)|$ stays the same… Probably you should rethink your formulation and check if you stated all the assumptions that you assume.

Comment: @Dirk: If you replace $y_i$ by $y_i +c$, then the question asks if $|y_i - f(i)|$ is at most $y_i + c$  (not $y_i$). So there is no point to do the transformation $y_i  \mapsto y_i + c$ for some $c \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it…

Comment: I'm working on this problem with Naiyong Ao, and encouraged him to post on here (as I couldn't easily answer the question).  Essentially, the question asks if $y_{n-1} < |y_i-f(i)|$ ever happens (or for a proof that it doesn't).  The restriction "$y_i$ is non-negative" means we can't decrease $y_{n-1}$ arbitrarily by uniformly subtracting a positive constant.  If $y_{n-1} < |y_i-f(i)|$ could arise, Naiyong Ao's code (which stores data points as a regression line and the deviations from that line as non-negative integers), an error could theoretically occur.